# As parent/child are for inheritance, what are the terms for composition?

Tags: oop, terminology

I'm not sure where to ask this this but I don't know how to google this. When class A inherits class B, A is child and B is Parent (or Base). If class C is composed of D(s), i.e. if C has D(s), what are the terms for C and D?

Comment: There are many possible terms and they can overlap in usage. When A inherits B: A is derived from B, or is a sub class of B, or is a child of B.  B is the base class or super class or parent class. In the case of C and D: D is a property or child of C, C is the owner or parent of D.  Because they are less ambiguous, I prefer to use the terms Derived and Base when describing inheritance relationships and Property and Owner when referring to composition relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about either "has-a" or "use-a" relationship. for example, in simple,if C has D as class property (like embedded property in C++) then it is called as "C has D",and if C only has pointer of D as property, it is called "C uses D".

Comment: Well, definitely, but I was expecting the terms like "C is called Composer and D is called Component". Unfortunately, it seems there's no widely accepted term like this, huh? Anyway, thanks for your answer.